# List of arguments for scheduled task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, arguments

When you edit the action of a Scheduled Task, there's the option of "Add arguments".

The software I use right now has the argument

```
-cp .\Acquisition.Jar et.EPC
```

I've been googling for a while and couldn't find what `-cp` does.

Is there a list somewhere of these arguments? Are they related to the program used and if so, how can I find the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is a `-cp` argument (option)

Your program is a Java program.

In this case you need to be aware that there are **options** and **arguments** which are different entities.

The **option** `-cp` (short for `-classpath`) specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files.

The other possible **options** for a Java program are documented in [java - Launches a Java application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

The values after the jar file name are **arguments** that are passed to the `main` method. You will need to refer to the documentation provided with the jar file to see the allowed **arguments** and their meaning.

---

#### The Java command line

> **Synopsis**
>
> `java [ options ] class [ arguments ]`
>
> `java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]`
>
> `javaw [ options ] class [ arguments ]`
>
> `javaw [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]`
>
> options
>
> - Command-line options. See Options.
>
> class
>
> - The name of the class to be called.
>
> file.jar
>
> - The name of the JAR file to be called. Used only with the -jar command.
>
> arguments
>
> - The arguments passed to the main function.

...

> **Standard Options**

...

> `-classpath classpath`
>
> `-cp classpath`
>
> Specifies a list of directories, JAR files, and ZIP archives to search for class files. Separate class path entries with semicolons
>   (;). Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the
>   CLASSPATH environment variable.
>
> If -classpath and -cp are not used and CLASSPATH is not set, then the user class path consists of the current directory (.).
>
> As a special convenience, a class path element that contains a base name of * is considered equivalent to specifying a list of all
>   the files in the directory with the extension .jar or .JAR. A Java
>   program cannot tell the difference between the two invocations.
>
> For example, if directory mydir contains a.jar and b.JAR, then the class path element mydir/* is expanded to a A.jar:b.JAR, except that
>   the order of jar files is unspecified. All jar files in the specified
>   directory, even hidden ones, are included in the list. A class path
>   entry consisting simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in
>   the current directory. The CLASSPATH environment variable, where
>   defined, will be similarly expanded. Any class path wildcard expansion
>   occurs before the Java VM is started. No Java program will ever see
>   wild cards that are not expanded except by querying the environment.
>   For example, by calling System.getenv("CLASSPATH").

Source [java - Launches a Java application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html Exactly what I was looking for. I hope these will be easy to find if I want to find arguments to another kind of software in the future

Comment: Great. They are not always so easy to find - search for "program command line" is usually a good place to start. I already knew exactly what I was looking for as I recognised a `java` command line in your question - I used to be a Java programmer ;)

Comment: +1  although @loli, it could be dangerious to assume that `-cp` will always mean this (in other program which may/may not be java based).

Comment: @Dave `command line "-cp"` returns lots of results for unix `cp` :/

Answer (score 3):

The argument is unique to the software, not to Task Scheduler.

I use this a lot when writing software, it's essentially a flag/command so when my program is run from task schedulder, it gets passed a value, such as file path and a command. The command tells my program what do with it.

EG, I have written some back up software, which runs from task scheduler. The parameter it passes is:

```
"path\file.bmup" -s
```

In this case the -s means it shows the GUI and doesn't just run in the background.

Or it could be

```
"path\file.bmup" -e
```

In this case, it sends an email when the program is finished.

As to what they mean - if the developers do not provide any documentation, it's very hard to know. There are some 'standards' but they only work if people follow the standards. EG, `-f` often means `force` but there is no reason my software can't read `-f` as `Finnish language`

Comment: Do you have any keyword to recommend me for finding these arguments? I tried googling with "arguments" or "parameters" but can't find anything.

Comment: @loli, may be. It depends on if the developers documented this. What is the software you are using?

Comment: @DavidPostill found it. But it's just that in general, I don't know what to search to find these arguments

Comment: You are using the correct words. They are called arguments or parameters... So, if you searched for `java parameters "-cp"` it may have helped

Comment: ah yes you're right. I didn't put java in the search because I didn't know it was related to the program used until you answered my question :)

Comment: @Dave "java command line" gives the reference as the first match ;)